# Render a user's projects in base template

Tags: django, django-models

I'm working on an project management app. On every page (all projects, new project, edit project etc) I want the user's projects to be present in a sidebar in the base template.

In the sidebar in the base template I have the following code for rendering out the user's projects:

```
  <h5>Your projects</h5>
  {% for project in user.projects.all %}
      {{ project }}<br/>
  {% endfor %}
```

However, this only renders *one* project, not *all* the projects. Why is that?

**the project model:**

```
class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    ... the rest of the fields ...
    added_by_user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='projects')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    def owned_by_user(self, user):
        return self.added_by_user == user
```

Comment: This is Rails, right? The font may be tricking me...

Comment: @holyredbeard Ah, this is where I walk awkwardly away...

Comment: @catherine: To be honest with you I just tried it because it felt logically. It works however (no errors), but again it just renders one project.

Comment: Are you sure the projects have the current user in their respective `users` set and not just `added_by_user`?

Comment: @catherine: Ah, so I'm on the right track at least :) Well, no I have no model named UserProfile, if that's what you mean?

Comment: hmmm...you can't render it correctly because project is not a property for user. Maybe try this one {% for project in user.projects_set.all %}

Comment: @catherine: tried your code but that renders nothing :/

Comment: you need to define a property that will connect user to your projects. I will be easy if you have userprofile model that extend user model.

Answer (score 0):

Usually this is done in a view, I like using render_to_response. If you're already using a number of views and you just want to include this information you would add the information to the view. You can pass as much or as little data as you need to in render_to_response

#### views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

def some_view(request,user_id):
    # other queries
    project_listing = Project.objects.filter(user = user_id): 
    return render_to_response('sometemplate.html', {"someother_query":someother_query,"project_listing":project_listing,}
```

#### templates/project_list.html

```
<h5>Your projects</h5>
<table>  
{% for project in project_listing %}
    <tr>
        <td>Project Name</td>
        <td>{{ project.name }}</td>
    </tr>
    .... repeat as necessary for each element 
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

#### templates/sometemplate.html

```
... other elements
{% include 'project_list.html' %}
... other elements
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I use views for all the functionality, but this case is different because this is only a part of the site and it should be visible on all the pages.

Comment: I've updated my answer. Basically, you just add it to the dictionary you're passing to render_to_response and then call your template for the queryset in the top level template.